# Configuration of Websockets on a REST API in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, websocket, spring-websocket

I need to add chat functionality to by web application, on which, the front end
is separated from the back end. The backend is a `rest api` build on Spring Boot.

From the examples I have seen the font end is created in a folder called `static`
under `resources` and then the application is run on a port.

So, as I understand, websockets do not use http, so how to I make calls to
the front end?

How do I test that the chat application is working? Without connecting to the font end?
When I run the main application, mongodb starts running, so not sure how i can run my
chat application. [Here is the application's strucure.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7zGPb.png)

I have read the other questions regardin Websockets and REST however none of the posts
goes in details about it, or answers my questions. Any other resources you may have are
welcome, as I couldn't find anything good myself.

Thank you.